# python robustly convert any string with units to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to convert any string (a number with units) to a float. I have a list of values like

```
myList = ["$800", "0.1mm", "54.6%", "100,000,000", "89.6", "1,017.16%"]
```

And I would like to convert it to:

```
myList = [800.0, 0.1, 54.6, 100000000.0, 89.6, 1017.16]
```

And I would like to do this without using multiple replaces stacked together .replace("%","").replace(",","").replace(...)...

I feel like there is a really easy pythonic solution...

Comment: This sounds like it'll just lead to weird problems with `'1m'` and `'1mm'` being treated as equal, even ignoring the dimension problems.

Comment: those string to numeric conversions are full of traps.

Comment: It is a slippery situation. If the list comes from your program, you may be better reconsidering the code that generates it, ie fixing the units of input and displaying them only at output.

Comment: What about `€80,00` or input from locales that use `,` as a decimal separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have used `str.translate`, but best way here is probably regex replacement since you can negate what you want to keep, i.e digits, dots, and minus signs.

```
import re
myList = ["$800", "0.1mm", "54.6%", "100,000,000", "89.6", "1,017.16%"]

newlist = [float(re.sub("[^0-9.\-]","",x)) for x in myList]

print(newlist)
```

result:

```
[800.0, 0.1, 54.6, 100000000.0, 89.6, 1017.16]
```

That converts every number to float. Could be refined to convert to int if no dot, for instance by chaining the comprehension with another one to discriminate candidates for integer conversion, like this:

```
newlist = [float(y) if "." in y else int(y) for y in (re.sub("[^0-9.\-]","",x) for x in myList)]
```

(doesn't take scientific notation into account, a `"E" in y` would have to be added if needed, and not filtered out by the regex.

Result is now:

```
[800, 0.1, 54.6, 100000000, 89.6, 1017.16]
```

Comment: The regex `[$a-z,%]` might not be fully robust. A better way to do it would be to use `[^0-9]`

Comment: you're right, apart from the fact that `.` must be added and also minus sign to handle possible negative values

Comment: Yeah, I need "." added... thanks, this is the response that works the best, but is close to becoming too specific (i.e adding in for scientific notation). I will mark this as the solution in a day or two if no one else has better option. thanks again

Comment: scientific notation is really a problem if you want to eliminate `e` after an integer for instance because it's part of an unit. In that case, it comes down to a very complex regex to be able to keep the `e` between digits, or between a digit and a minus sign and discard the others... nightmare :)

Comment: This will is not considering scientific notations like: 2.0e+2 or 100.4e6 MPa

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the list by iterating through each item and only keeping values that are numeric with the `isdigit()` builtin function.

```
myList = ["$800", "0.1mm", "54.6%", "100,000,000", "89.6", "1,017.16%"]
new_list = []
for i in myList:
    f = ''.join(x for x in i if x.isdigit() or x in ['.', '-'])
    new_list.append(float(f))
```

or, for a single line expression:

```
new_list = [float(''.join([x for x in y if x.isdigit() or x in ['.', '-'])) for y in myList]
```

EDIT: missed including decimals and negatives. fixed. not sure about supporting notation such as 1.2e384

EDIT2: in general, this whole situation is really unsafe practice and i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Also minus signs, and a decision needs to be made about whether to support `1.2e15` notation.

Comment: Goodpoint user2357112, it could spiral into a frankensteined expression for more cases with lots of "or" statements

Comment: So you are thinking there is no general solution to converting string numbers with units (or commas, negatives, etc.) to floats?

Comment: @laserpython the answer i posted will handle most cases. scientific notation and e-notation, however, will not be accounted for, and in turn cause some very wrong values. this would take a lot more work and a pretty hefty function to iterate through each item, identify it's notation, and act accordingly. unfortunately, there are so many different forms of notation that this can get sloppy VERY quick and easily.

Comment: @laserpython for example, an e-notation of `1.2e384` will return `1.2384`... and a scientific notation of `7.51x10-9` will return `7.51109` or a `SyntaxError` depending on the characters used for `x` and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex module in python

```
import re
list = ["$800", "0.1mm", "54.6%", "100,000,000", "89.6", "1,017.16%"]
subbed_list = [float(re.sub('[^0-9.\-]','',i)) for i in list]
```

Comment: This is great but doesn't take into account the "."

Comment: I've added the ".", it was a small oversight on my part.

Comment: @NickA Edited in

Comment: But now it's the same as Jean-Francois' answer?